# get the count occurrence of series in another series

Tags: python, pandas

```
final['connection_received'] = final['USERS_ID'].map(connect.receiverId.value_counts())
final['connection_sent'] = final['USERS_ID'].map(connect.senderId.value_counts())
```

so i have two dataframe, first one contains unique user ids and the second one contains senderid and receiver id, i want to get the count of of unique user id in both senderid and receiverid. the above code kinda works to some extents but I get some NaN values in the result. i need help please.

```
unique userid
0   5ef5dfdb2ab4cf551d8bcfd4
1   5ef5ea68df376c7656e0c1ec
2   5ef5f5b7df376c7656e0c1f1
3   5ef6156f2ab4cf551d8bcfde
4   5ef5fe652ab4cf551d8bcfdb
... ...
322 5fc4d2413123380b3f777afb
323 5fce259e3123380b3f777d4e
    324 5f32ad274483621fb211238c
    325 5ef74dce2ab4cf551d8bcff3
    326 5fc678b73123380b3f777b61e2 


second df

    receiverId                   senderId
0   5f3448ab4483621fb21123d5    5ef5dfdb2ab4cf551d8bcfd4
1   5f03020facd87760903626d9    5ef5ea68df376c7656e0c1ec
2   5efb05152ab4cf551d8bd008    5ef5f5b7df376c7656e0c1f1
3   5f3469e35200894c03909f4e    5ef5ea68df376c7656e0c1ec
4   5ef5e8692ab4cf551d8bcfd5    5ef5f5b7df376c7656e0c1f1
... ... ...
2115    5fce5896a086492703672926    5fc678b73123380b3f777b61
2116    5fce54a9a086492703672924    5fc678b73123380b3f777b61
2117    5fce43d83123380b3f777d5d    5fc678b73123380b3f777b61
2118    5fce41e8a08649270367291c    5fc678b73123380b3f777b61
2119    5fce36c33123380b3f777d59    5fc678b73123380b3f777b61
```

I want to see the count of times each unique id occurs in receiverid and senderID column. thanks

Comment: perhaps you need to clean the data first to dropna if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're getting `NaN` because there're ID's on `df2` not present in `df1`. You can check which IDs are not present in `df1` with:

```
df1[~df1['unique userid'].isin(np.unique(df2.values))]
```

That said, you can do the following:

```py
df2 = (df2.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
 .rename_axis('unique userid')
 .reset_index()
)

final = df1.merge(df2, how='outer').fillna(0)
final.iloc[:, 1:] = out.iloc[:, 1:].astype(int)
final.columns = ['USERS_ID', 'connection_received', 'connection_sent']
```

where `df1` is your fist df (*i.e.* final), and `df2` the second one (*i.e.* connect).

Then, for retrieving the counts for a given ID:

```py
# Retrieve both counts of receiverId and senderId:
final[final.USERS_ID=='5ef5dfdb2ab4cf551d8bcfd4']
# Retrieve counts for receiverId
final[final.USERS_ID=='5ef5dfdb2ab4cf551d8bcfd4', 'connection_received']
# Retrieve counts for senderId
final[final.USERS_ID=='5ef5dfdb2ab4cf551d8bcfd4', 'connection_sent']
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but what i will like to achieve is something like this con_df[con_df.receiverId == '5f7b4aef8de24971d492fe17'] and keep track of the value count

Comment: You can use `final[final.USERS_ID=='5f7b4aef8de24971d492fe17']` to keep track of the value count for both receiverId and senderId (see update).

Comment: you got me wrong, the series is like 4000 rows much and i cant use this method to get the result

Comment: my goal is to check if each row of df1 is present in df2 and how many occurrence, it is.

Comment: The size of the dataframe doesn't matter at all (is it really a DataFrame, or a Series?). Changing the merge to `how='left'` will get you the unique rows of `df1` and how many occurrences there are for receiverId and senderId. If both "connection_received" and "connection_sent" is 0 for an user ID, then you know that row is no present in `df2`.

Comment: i have been able to get some result with this merge code  `final = user_df.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='_id', right_on='unique userid').fillna(0)`

Comment: @ Cainã Max Couto-Silva can you please take a look at this question for me?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242052/merge-daily-activities-of-connections-separate-between-sender-and-receiver-activ?noredirect=1#comment115342794_65242052